# Check if all three columns are either not null or null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-server-2012, check-constraints

I have a table with 4 columns:

```sql
create table dbo.Table ( 
  Id int not null,
  A int null,
  B int null,   
  C nvarchar (4000) null
)
```

How can I make sure that `A`, `B` and `C` are all three `null` or all three `not null`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set a [`check constraint`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx):

```sql
constraint [check_abc] check ( ([A] is null and [B] is null and [C] is null) or
                               ([A] is not null and [B] is not null and [C] is not null) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider factoring these related columns out to a second table in which they are declared `not null` and only inserting a row where they apply.

```
create table dbo.Table1( 
  Id int not null primary key
)


create table dbo.Table2( 
  Id int not null primary key references Table1,
  A int not null,
  B int not null,   
  C nvarchar (4000) not null
)
```